# DNS Unlocker version 1.4 Malware is isntalling into windows automatically with out permissions

Tags: dns, ads, user-permissions, virus

DNS Unlocker version 1.4 is an application which is automatically installing itself into my windows without administrative permissions.

What it does it hacks all my browsers and show ads on every page causes redirection to malicious websites and slows down my PC.

Other special thing it changes the Preferred DNS IP address to something else.

I have tired a lot methods to remove it form system but I couldn't succeed  yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS Unlocker installs a service in your computer Named as "DNS Client" which starts automatically.

Solution: Just disable it from you Local services you'll get rid from all this browser attacks.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating, I found out that the damn "DNS Unlocker" had modified my DNS settings! After fixing this I was completely good! I have google chrome, so I am unsure if this fix persist to other browsers.
The path to do this follows:
Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings > Right-click your active internet connection (usually Wi-Fi since everyone uses that, unless your using a desktop) and click properties > Now under the Networking tab, scroll down until you find Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) > Highlight that then click on properties > Both options in this windows should be automatic! The first option should be set to "Obtain an IP address automatically" and the second should be set to "Obtain DNS server address automatically!" If your computer belongs to a company or you actually have a custom DNS then this would not apply to you. Once you are finish, click "OK" and close the windows > Now go back into Chrome and reset your settings one more time and boom! It should work just fine.

Comment: but it will start doing again after few hours or minutes untill unless you disable it's service.

Answer (score 0):

"Ads by DNSUnlocker" is a browser based virus, I solved this issue on my windows 7 by Removing unwanted DNS entries from internet connection(in Windows 7, right click on the network icon(right-bottom corner on screen)-> Network and Sharing Center -> internet connection(Local Area Network link -> Properties -> IPv4 -> Properties)
select "Obtain DNS server address automatically" and click "Advanced"->DNS -> remove ip addresses if any on the DNS server addresses box.

Comment: HI Bruce, I already had tried this trick but the problem is this when you remove those ip addresses this DNSUnlocker adds them again there, like sometime after few minutes sometime after few hours and sometimes after few days. I had faced it, and I know you'll face it as well, I haven't yet found any best solution for it, when I'll find I'll must share with you all.

Comment: Check if you have an application named "Ads by DNSUnlocker" in your control panel and uninstall it, also remove browser plugins (chrome extensions) with similar name if any.

Comment: I knwo about all these things, problem was very severe it installs this DNS Unlocker application again automatically with any permissions. I have experieced it may times by deleting it and deleting browser extenions and plugins. Problem is some thing else, what I think it is running a service from where it does all these oprations.

Comment: May be you havn't encounter the problem that I am facing. But my suggestions is this you need to find out about services that from which service it is doing all these things.

Comment: Hey Bruce, What I am planning to write a windows service to notfiy me when there is new installationa and when there is change gonna happen in DNS IP address. And system will show me which service or event is going to make these changes is a good solution seems to me can significantly help to me and other effected people.